# Is there a default clipboard history in Ubuntu? If there is, how can I access it?

Tags: 20.04, clipboard, history

Is there a default clipboard history in Ubuntu 20.04 or later? If there is, how can I access it? I know there are lots of available applications for saving clipboard history in the default Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: I was a bit surprised by this, but it's true, I just tried my ubuntu 21.04 and it doesn't have a clipboard history. But I mostly use my other installation, which is kubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, and it *does* have a clipboard with history (accessed via the menubar).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There isn't a default clipboard history in 20.04, just the current item in the clipboard or nothing if nothing has been copied to the clipboard. If nothing has been copied to the clipboard, the clipboard is empty. If something has been copied to the clipboard then by default the clipboard contains the last item that was copied to it.

Pasting a selected text snippet with your middle mouse button is completely separate from the normal clipboard. Selecting text does not copy it to your clipboard. This quick method of pasting only works with the middle mouse button. For more information visit [GNOME help Middle-click](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/mouse-middleclick.html.en).

Answer (score 58):

You can give "CopyQ" a try, from Ubuntu Software store.

Comment: CopyQ (`sudo apt install copyq`) is an advanced clipboard manager with editing and scripting features. CopyQ monitors system clipboard and saves its content in customized tabs. Saved clipboard can be later copied and pasted directly into any application.

Comment: Thank you, it helped me. Especially after assigning a shortcut `Super` + `V` to act like Windows clipboard.

Comment: This worked for me as well. However, I found adding the `Super` + `V` Global Shortcut through the app that I had to press it twice for it to work . Instead, I assigned the `Super` + `V` shortcut through Ubuntu's Settings -> Keyboard Shortcuts, adding a custom one that runs a command `copyq menu` that brings up the tray menu.

Comment: As a shortcut, I use `CTRL` + `Super` + `V` without any problem, as `Super` + `V` is already captured by default.

Comment: sudo apt install copyq not work in my ubuntu16

Comment: Man, thanks a lot for CopyQ. "Paste on selection" feature is super useful

Comment: It doesn't see my clipboard on Ubuntu 23.10. Also, the UI is ugly - it probably uses older Qt/KDE libs.

Comment: Ivan, it looks to me an issue in Ubuntu 23 (Wayland VS X11 internals), so please look at CopyQ forums/docs.

Answer (score 21):

I am now using ClipIt - https://github.com/CristianHenzel/ClipIt in my Ubuntu 20.04 ever since I have posted this question and am happy with it, everything is okay in terms of performance, features and etc. You can install it via ubuntu software or flathub or just click github link and follow the installation instruction they have provided in their github repo.

Comment: I install `clipit` from the Ubuntu APT repositories. When I run it, this message is displayed: "ClipIt has been deprecated and is no longer supported in Ubuntu. Diodon, a supported replacement for ClipIt, has been automatically installed for your convenience". The GitHub repo says that the version in the Debian and Ubuntu repositories is broken.

Comment: I don't have any problem with my installation, it's a bit longer since I posted this question and successfully installed clipit and still using clipit til this time. I have googled "diodon clipit", and you're right, "clipit" has been replaced by "diodon" in debian official package. 
Here's the link of the debian official package,
https://packages.debian.org/sid/clipit

Answer (score 6):

I've released a [clipboard manager Gnome extension](https://github.com/SUPERCILEX/gnome-clipboard-history) which is a rewrite of Clipboard Indicator with vastly improved performance, new features, and bug fixes.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 6):

## GPaste

[image]

You can download it with

```bash
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extensions-gpaste
```

By default the history will by shown by pressing `<Ctrl><Alt>H`, it can also be called with the command `gpaste-client show-history`

Comment: for me (ubuntu22.04) i never got to work **Gpaste** probably (e.g. couldn't set up hotkeys). But *Qlipper** does the job for me. It also offers "sticky entries" for thinks you use often e.g. your email

Answer (score 2):

Go to https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/779/clipboard-indicator/ and install it.

Make sure you have the Firefox add-on of Gnome-shells website https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/gnome-shell-integration/?utm_source=addons.mozilla.org&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=search

You will have a clipboard on the top bar you can access. It resets after shutdown by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Go for [Clipman](https://docs.xfce.org/panel-plugins/clipman/start) if you are using Xfce.

Answer (score 1):

I really like [gnome-shell-pano](https://github.com/oae/gnome-shell-pano).

[image]

You need to install libgda and gsound for this extension to work.

```
sudo apt install gir1.2-gda-5.0 gir1.2-gsound-1.0
```